# R: Summing rows in a loop based on rowname

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

I am new to R and would find some tips very helpful.

I have populated matrix X that has lists of rownames which are numeric.

These correspond to matrix (Y).

I would like to summate all the rows in matrix Y based on the rownames in Matrix X.

So X[,1] may contain a list of rownames which I want to extract the row sums of these particular rows in matrix Y.

I think where I'm having difficulty is where to put the rownames() in the statements - I've tried many different combinations using functions, with and if. Any guidance or tips would be very gratefully received. Thank you.

I have provided a simplified version of the problem below:

```
    X              Y
    1 2            10  10  10
    3 3            20  20  20
    5 4            30  30  30
                   40  40  40
                   50  50  50

    Z[1] (X[,1]) should equal [10+10+10]+[30+30+30]+[50+50+50]
    Z[2] (X[,2]) should equal [20+20+20]+[30+30+30]+[40+40+40]
```

Z should be a vector of sums of Y's rows depending on the column of X's row name values.

Comment: what is your desired output, one number or a vector? is `sum(Y[X[, 1], ])` or `rowSums(Y[X[, 1], ])` close?

Comment: Isn't it just `z <- rowSums(Y); sapply(X, function(x) sum(z[x]))`? Edit: Hadn't seen the edit yet, @rawr, but yeah, the first option I'd say.

Comment: My desired output would be a vector of sums of matrix Y's rows based on the rownames in each column of X. Sorry I should have said this is a simplified version of the problem. My matrices are much bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this as follows:

```
x <- data.frame(x)
sapply(x, function(r) sum(y[r, ]))
```

Output is:

```
 X1  X2 
270 270
```

Alternatively, you can name columns of `matrix` `x` and supply them to sapply. In this case, I went with easy conversion of `x` to data frame.

Comment: I should have not re-used `x` as the function argument as it confuses. Really, `sapply` feeds a column of `x` to the function, which is used to index into rows of `y` to do the sum.

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on `data.table` and `reshape2` packages:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

X <- matrix(c(1,3,5,2,3,4), nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
Y <- 10*matrix(rep(1:5, each = 3), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)

# Convert to data.table
X.DT <- data.table(X)
Y.DT <- data.table(Y)

Z.DT <- 
  # First melt the X to get the column names as grouping 'variable'
  # and the numeric values in 'value'
  melt(X.DT, measure.vars = names(X.DT))[
    # Sum the values of Y selected by the indicies stored in X 
  , .(Z = sum(Y.DT[value]))
  , by = variable
]

Z.DT
```

Result looks like this:

```
   variable   Z
1:       V1 270
2:       V2 270
```

And if you need the result as a simple vector Z then you can do it like this:

```
Z <- Z.DT[,Z]
Z
[1] 270 270
```

For reference, the intermediary `data.table` that is returned by the `melt` function looks like this:

```
> melt(X.DT, measure.vars = names(X.DT))
   variable value
1:       V1     1
2:       V1     3
3:       V1     5
4:       V2     2
5:       V2     3
6:       V2     4
```

Comment: Thank you! Those packages look very useful.

Comment: You are welcome! For any real-world data work, I do not attempt doing it without 'data.table'.

Comment: I see! I will definitely be using the data table command more in future.